# Conditional Where statement on a table valued parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm building a query that has a bunch of optional parameters, some of which are Table-Valued Parameters. The problem that I'm facing is how to most efficiently use the TVPs in this query?

**Each TVP has the type:**

```
TABLE( [variable] nvarchar(30))
```

**I know that I could typically:**

```
INNER JOIN @TVP
```

to filter out anything that is not in the TVP list, but what if I decide not to pass any values to the TVP in my query? Then nothing will be returned (because of the inner join)

**Usually this is accomplished with a conditional where statement:**

```
WHERE (SomeVar = @SameVar OR @SameVar IS NULL)
```

But, with a TVP, it can't be null (at least not that I've found)

**One way I have found to accomplish this is:**

```
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT TOP(1) * from dbo.SomeTable tbl where tbl.SomeVar in 
(select * from @TVP) or not exists (select * from @TVP)
AND tbl.SomeVar = SomeVar)
```

Unfortunately this method is horridly slow

**Alternatively, I've tried:**

```
WHERE (tbl.SomeVar in (SELECT * FROM @TVP) or not exists (SELECT * from @TVP))
```

This is MUCH faster, but I still feel like it may not be ideal

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!  Let me know if I can clarify anything....Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

So, I've come up with this, and will probably use it unless someone has a better solution:

```
INNER JOIN @TVP tvp
ON (tvp.SomeVar = tbl.SomeVar or tvp.SomeVar is null)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
   DECLARE @UseTVP int
   SET @UseTVP = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TVP) 

   SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM dbo.SomeTable tbl
            LEFT JOIN @TVP tvp
                ON tbl.SomeVar = tvp.SomeVar
        WHERE (tvp.SomeVar IS NOT NULL
               OR @UseTVP = 0)
```

Comment: So, what if I am not using the TVP during a query? Then it will always be null, and I'll get no results, right? How do I make using the TVP optional?

Comment: @Brett: I've edited my answer. Not sure if this is any better than what you've already tried.

Comment: That looks pretty good, I think I'll profile the two methods that I've got now, and go from there.... thanks for your help!

Comment: This little nugget is awesome! We are restricted to sql2005, so no TVPs, but regardless this approach basically allows you to do conditional joins on 'lists' of parameters passed in (basically a delimited string then parsed into #temp table) and allow for the case where the list may be null ie not passed and no filtering is done on that parameter, essentially returning 'all'. You can do a LEFT JOIN on the new 'tvp' and add another "AND [list parameter].SomeVar IS NOT NULL OR @Use[List for that parameter] = 0". Took me a while to work out how but this answer, well, was the answer.

Comment: ...you could of course OR the parameter list ie "OR [list parameter].SomeVar IS NOT NULL OR @Use[List for that parameter] = 0" or whatever you query requires :-)